# run a command when a specific folder is empty

Tags: command-line, nohup

I have a python script running which will loop through a folder files (do some work then delete the files there), the folder will eventually get emptied.

I want to run this command when the folder reaches 0 files

```
nohup python3 create_images.py > my_log.txt&
```

I have been using this command to keep track of the process

```
ls -al images|wc -l
```

is it possible to automatically monitor the number of files then run my command directly?

Comment: Since you are already using python, I'd personally prefer to do all of it in python. As @Jurrie pointed out in their answer, `inotify` is probably the solution for your problem. There is also a [python library](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/) for that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a 100% answer to your question, but...

There is a utility called `inotifywait` (`sudo apt-get install inotify-tools`) which allows you to listen for events on given files or directories. In the default mode, it listens for events on a given file or directory, and will exit when something is changed / read / deleted / etc. Definitely check `man inotifywait` for all the options.

I use `inotifywait` in some of my scripts inside a loop:

1. `inotifywait <your dir>`
2. Check if directory is empty, and run your command if it is
3. back to 1.

I think getting this to work 100% accurately is rather tricky, as there is a chance for race conditions going from step 3 to 1. But I thought I'd post this anyway, as it just might work for your situation.

Comment: As mentioned, I made it python to check if the folder is empty or not (do nothing), anyway thanks for your help

Comment: Inotifywait is using kernel functions for the actual work. I do not do Python that often, but it seems there is a Python project to use inotify from Python: https://pypi.org/project/inotify/